# TFS and team project portal question

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, tfs, moss

The team explorer for my project looks like this:

```
mytfsserver\mycollection
-- Project 1 solution
-- Project 2 solution
-- Project 3 solution
```

When I right click on one of the solutions and do a "Show Project Portal", I see the following hierarchy:

```
mycollection - WSS site
Project 1 site with dashboard (appears to be a MOSS site)
Project 2 site with dashboard (appears to be a MOSS site)
Project 3 site with dashboard (appears to be a MOSS site)
```

Are the dashboard sites MOSS sites? If I want to create a wiki, do I have to create a subsite with the wiki template under each of the Project sites?

Can someone point me to a document/video that talks about the sites that area created by TFS by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and created a new WIKI subsite

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Sharepoint Foundation / Sharepoint Services than this is NOT a MOSS site and the reports you are seeing are Reporting services reports.

If you are using a MOSS enviroment to host your sites then they will indeed be MOSS, but from your description it does not sound like it.

These are just standard Sharepoint sites with a little TFS Magic. Just lookup some Sharepoint documentation, but you can add a Wiki like you would add a Document Libuary adn in fact Sharepoint Wikies are Documetn Libuary's with Wiki pages in it.

Comment: So, are you saying that it's not necessary to create a WIKI subsite under the dasboard sites and I should just add a document library which is a WIKI?